# How to get version of meteor on meteor.com

Tags: meteor

If I deploy my app using:

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

How can I check the version of meteor running on the remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply evaluate [`Meteor.release`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_release) in your app code.

> Meteor.release is a string containing the name of the release with which the project was built (for example, "0.7.1.1"). It is undefined if the project was built using a git checkout of Meteor.

Also note that every project is pinned to a specific release of Meteor. Demo at http://release.meteor.com/ - note the release is Windows, which is clearly not what meteor.com runs :)

Comment: I can build my app to run on any version, so let's say I build it for v6.0 and then deploy it - will it then run under v6.0 or will it use the version installed on the meteor.com servers?

Comment: It should keep running on v0.6. From [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorupdate): Every project is pinned to a specific release of Meteor. You can temporarily try using your package with another release by passing the `--release` option to any command; `meteor update` simply changes the pinned release.

Comment: I understand the version targeting system when running locally but wasn't sure what happens when you  deploy. So you're saying that my app will in the deployed environment under whatever version I built it with?

Comment: Yes - see http://release.meteor.com/. I've just deployed an app that I created on my Windows box.